# c++ - managing entities in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `std::vector<Enemy> enemies`. At the end of the constructor of the `Enemy` class I do `enemies.push_back(*this)`, although I'm not really sure this is the best way, or really why I need the pointer besides that I get an error without it.

During the destructor, i'd like to do something like:

```
enemies.erase(std::find(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), *this));
```

But that doesn't really work out too well.

Basically, when an `Enemy` is instantiated I'd like it to go into the `enemies` vector, and when destroyed, removed.

Comment: Sounds like you want an `std::vector<Enemy *>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't done this in forever.

Comment: I suspect explaining *why* you're managing a vector of **copies** of every `Enemy` object (or sliced derivative thereof) may expose a more-fundamental design issue. It may be something as simple as suggested; simply using the wrong type in the first place.

Comment: @EvanWard - Make sure that what you want is really `std::vector<Enemy*>` and not just that you're using it to make the compiler happy.  You don't want to introduce a vector of pointers if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to refine the question a bit more: What is the scope of std::vector enemies?

To answer the first part of the question: enemies has been declared to be a vector and not a pointer to Enemy. This is why you have to generate a reference by doing "*this" as an argument to push_back() call. You are effectively keeping a copy of all the objects constructed in this vector.

Is that your intent or do you mean it to be a registry of some kind, that is keeping track of all the Enemy objects created? If it is a registry that you want:

please use `std::vector<Enemy*> enemies`.

Please try to be specific about "doesn't really work out too well".

I think people can give better answers, if you give a bit more context.

Answer (score 1):

The `vector` stores **copies** of the objects, so the `push_back()` stores a copy (it doesn't enter a loop of constructors only because it uses the default copy constructor to create that copy, which won't do a second `push_back`), which means you're inadvertently duplicating objects, so it won't behave as expected.

Also

> At the end of the constructor of the Enemy class I do
>   enemies.push_back(*this), although I'm not really sure this is the
>   best way, or really why I need the pointer besides that I get an error
>   without it.

`this` is a pointer to that Enemy
`*this` is a reference to that Enemy

You can't add `this` to the vector because it's a pointer and your vector is not comprised of pointers.